# Adding seekbar to Media Player or migrate to Exoplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, leanback

I'am setting up an offline channel app using google leanback library and was able to play videos from an external source (hard drive) and not from the internet using media player. Since it is very limited, i would like to transfer or migrate to exoplayer but i am having a hard time doing it. I like to add the functionality of back and forward or like a seekbar.

Tried exoplayer, transport control glue etc. but all of them fetch data from the internet but mine uses external hard drive. Cannot make it run.

```
/**
 * Handles video playback with media controls.
 */
public class PlaybackVideoFragment extends VideoSupportFragment {

    private PlaybackTransportControlGlue<MediaPlayerAdapter> 
    mTransportControlGlue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Movie movie = (Movie) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(DetailsActivity.MOVIE);

        VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost glueHost =
                new VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost(PlaybackVideoFragment.this);

        MediaPlayerAdapter playerAdapter = new MediaPlayerAdapter(getActivity());
        playerAdapter.setRepeatAction(PlaybackControlsRow.RepeatAction.INDEX_NONE);
        playerAdapter.seekTo(PlaybackControlsRow.SkipNextAction.NO_ID);


        mTransportControlGlue = new PlaybackTransportControlGlue<>(getActivity(), playerAdapter);
        mTransportControlGlue.setHost(glueHost);
        mTransportControlGlue.setTitle(movie.getTitle());
        mTransportControlGlue.setSubtitle(movie.getDescription());
        mTransportControlGlue.playWhenPrepared();


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mTransportControlGlue != null) {
            mTransportControlGlue.pause();
        }
    }

}
```

I would like to add a functionality like a seekbar

Comment: what exactly you want to do

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response to my question. My channel app does not use internet streaming, it gets it data (videos, images, etc.) from an attached storage hard drive. I am having a hard time figuring on how will i migrate from mediaplayer to exoplayer so i can have back and forward functionality. I really need your expertise on this matter.

Comment: you can check given answer its nice example